Intermittent Test Failures with Resolver in Unit Tests
I use the Resolver dependency injection framework in my iOS project and unit tests. Some tests fail intermittently when run together (CMD + U), but they succeed when run independently.
For example, here's a test case that fails:
ViewModel
final class DefaultSuccessViewModel: SuccessViewModel {
    @LazyInjected private var navigator: DefaultNavigator<Destination>
    override func onUIEvent(_ event: SuccessViewIntent) {
        if case .onMainTap = event { navigator.popToRoot() }
    }
}

MockNavigator:
public class MockDefaultNavigator<Destination: Hashable>: DefaultNavigator<Destination> {
    public private(set) var popToRootCallsCount = 0
    override public func popToRoot() {
        popToRootCallsCount += 1
        super.popToRoot()
    }
}

Tests:
class DefaultSuccessViewModelTests {
    private let sut: DefaultSuccessViewModel
    private let mockNavigator: MockDefaultNavigator<Destination>

    init() {
        let mockNavigator = MockDefaultNavigator<Destination>()
        Resolver.main.register { mockNavigator as DefaultNavigator<Destination> }
        self.mockNavigator = mockNavigator
        sut = DefaultSuccessViewModel()
    }

    @Test
    func onUIEvent_onItemTap_popsToRoot() {
        sut.onUIEvent(.onMainTap)
        #expect(mockNavigator.popToRootCallsCount == 1)
    }
}

The test passes when run independently but sometimes fails when run with others (CMD + U).
I suspect the MockDefaultNavigator state (popToRootCallsCount) is shared across tests.
How can I isolate MockDefaultNavigator between tests to avoid shared state? Why does this issue occur?

When this happens, then the runnings test may accidentally interfere with each other. Note, that when a test function returns, their effects may still running. These effects may originate from objects created in the test or in  the test host, but still running asynchronously after the test function returns. Ensure you really only return the test function when all effects completed. Also, use a test host, which is the most simple App providing the minimal infrastructure (for example, a KeyChain, UserDefaults), but don't use the actual App as test host. Ideally, your test functions are pure.

Having said this, tests may run in parallel. When you access a shared resource, you might run into conflicts. In DefaultSuccessViewModelTests you might create a local MockDefaultNavigator  in each test function. Also, the shared Resolver might be an issue too. Can you use a local Resolver, as well?

But MockDefaultNavigator is injected in ViewModel using Resolver. That's a problem. Otherwise I could create local instances for each test and none of the issues would happen.

Yes, every test should not use shared mutable data (also not mutable instance variables from the SUT class or the test class itself, since the test functions might run in parallel ). Ideally, a test is a "pure function", which means, it does not access any data beyond its parameters, neither does it read, nor write anything from the outer world. Even just reading the current date with Date() in the test function, makes the test nondeterministic, since its result depends on when it is called. So, instead you would provide the date, as a parameter in the test function.

Man I know the theory :D yes, your suggestions are correct. I just need to know how to inject Mock implementations using Resolver and do it in thread safe way. Can u help me on that?

You should also not use the default Resolver, aka Resolver.main. It should be possible to use a separate instance of the Resolver in every test function. There are  several initialisers available. There should be one which is suitable. Please take a look into the sources. :)

Ohps, now I see, in case of the Resolver, @LazyInjected  might always implicitly use the main Resolver. We can imagine, that - when tests run in parallel - that there might be race conditions (not data races, since Resolver uses locks to make it thread-safe). So, one test injects A, and the other test overrides it with B, for the same dependency key. I have no solution for this issue, yet. It seems, you need to structure your tests - for example, pre-populate the Resolver with all mocks for all tests, such that this is not an issue. Otherwise, it's an issue with the DI framework.

Note: LazyInjected  has an initialiser which takes an optional resolver as parameter. So, in order to support proper testing capabilities, you would need to get this resolver from somewhere, then provide it  in the initialiser for the class which uses the DI, and set it explicitly in the property wrapper. I know, this sounds cumbersome, and it is. :(

So, in order to solve the potential race conditions in the DI during running tests in parallel, provide the Resolver in the initialiser of the class using the DI. If the resolver is nil, the default resolver (aka main) will be used.
final class DefaultSuccessViewModel: SuccessViewModel {

    init(name: Resolver.Name? = nil, container: Resolver? = nil) {
        $navigator.name = name
        $navigator.container = container
    }

    @LazyInjected private var navigator: DefaultNavigator<Destination>
    
    override func onUIEvent(_ event: SuccessViewIntent) {
        if case .onMainTap = event { navigator.popToRoot() }
    }
}

In the test, you would need to create a local resolver instance and dependencies in every test function:
class DefaultSuccessViewModelTests {

    init() {}

    @Test
    func onUIEvent_onItemTap_popsToRoot() {
        let resolver = Resolver() 
        let sut = DefaultSuccessViewModel(container: resolver)
        let mockNavigator = MockDefaultNavigator<Destination>()
        resolver.register { mockNavigator as DefaultNavigator<Destination> }
        sut.onUIEvent(.onMainTap)
        #expect(mockNavigator.popToRootCallsCount == 1)
    }
}

Note, that the dependencies might use other objects which access shared mutable state, in which case you might also get conflicts and race conditions. It's best to "mock away" all these dependencies and ensure that a test only depends on local instances and does not change or access anything from shared state outside the test.

This works as expected. Thanks!
